# What was this historic object used for?

Tags: meteorology, history-of-science, history

This object is displayed in an exhibition, but nobody knows what it is.
It was part of the estate of a photographer whose father was one of the first meteorologists in Switzerland.

[image: unknown meteorological object1]

**EDIT:**
Adding more detailed pictures upon request in the comments.

[image: unknown meteorological object2]

[image: unknown meteorological object6]

[image: unknown meteorological object5]

[image: unknown meteorological object4]

[image: unknown meteorological object3]

Comment: I  suggest adding several more pictures from different angles, if it has multiple parts showing that would help, right now it could be a sausages press for all you can tell from a single photo.

Comment: I've seen similar objects in meteorology before.  Traditional barometers were pretty big things once upon a time, especially if not using mercury (though perhaps bigger than this if water/alcohol??)  So I would think there's a good chance it's meteorological indeed, but not knowledgeable enough on old equipment myself.

Comment: is there any markings on the objects,letters or numbers? maybe you can give us the nameof the person owning this contraption.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll provide more photos asap. The separate object is semispherical. The object must be from 1829–1909 or newer (but less likely). Today's owners would not like to disclose the original owner's (OO) name for privacy reasons. But the OO was a later-founded Swiss Society of Natural Sciences member. Also, this link https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=sng-005%3A1864%3A48#230 describes devices they used, but none of the descriptions matches, afaik.

Comment: @njuffa sry, I was wrong in my last comment. The separate objects are cone-shaped. And indeed, the manufacturer's name remains partly as "W.J. Rohrb*" from Berlin. Does this help you classify the object?

Comment: @MatD. It could be "W.J. Rohrbeck", as in this illustrated catalogue of [apparatus for the physical sciences](https://books.google.com/books?id=4SxbAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) from 1856.

Comment: @MatD.the only reason for me to ask about the name of the original owner is to be able to search for published material that can identify the object.thank you for the added details in your question.

Comment: You could try asking the question at the History of sciences and mathematics Stack Exchange.